# How to remove linux end of line but leave windows line ending intact in bash?

Tags: linux, bash, command-line, command-line-interface

So I have a file that has mixed line endings. I need to remove only linux Line Feed (LF) but leave windows line endings alone(RFLF). Any quick bash one liner that can do this?

Comment: how about open&save the file in windows? :)

Comment: What do you mean by remove? Should `foo\nbar\r\nbaz` become `foobar\r\nbaz`? Or do you want to convert LF to CRLF, giving `foo\r\nbar\r\nbaz`?

Comment: I am asking exactly how my question is worded. Remove means it is gone gone. not there anymore(deleting it) Not converting. If I did ask how to convert I will mention converting. But thanks for the concern though.

Comment: It seems that your question would be answered by the _now deleted answer_: `<text.txt tr -d '\n' > tmp.txt && mv -- tmp.txt text.txt`

Answer (score 2):

If you want to convert all line endings to Windows line endings:

```
unix2dos file.txt
```

if you have it. Otherwise:

```
sed -i 's/\r\?$/\r/' file.txt
```

If you want to remove all LF endings (i.e. join lines) but keep CRLF:

```
<file.txt tr -d '\n' | tr '\r' '\n' | sed 's/$/\r/' >file.txt.new && mv file.txt.new file.txt
```

Comment: It appears that the last line is syntactically incorrect.

Comment: @devnull should be better now

Answer (score 0):

Perl to the rescue:

```
perl -pe 'chomp unless /\r$/'
```

Comment: The only problem with this solution is when there is LF it is replacing it with RFLF. It should have been replaced with nothing. Which is a definition of removal. Means it is gone. Not being replaced by another type of line ending.

Comment: Yes, and it does remove LF, but it leaves RFLF in place of LF.

Comment: @DoodleKana: `echo $'a\nb\r\nc' |  perl -pe 'chomp unless /\r$/' | xxd` shows `6162 0d0a 63`. I don't see any CRLF in place of LF.

Answer (score 0):

Try one of these utilities: dos2unix or tofrodos

Comment: Not what I am asking. I know about those tools. dos2unix and unix2dos. But these tools will convert all line endings. Read my question carefully again.